# Is an OS more vulnerable while it is being updated?

Tags: network, penetration-test, vulnerability, account-security, operating-systems

Are there any additional attack vectors that apply when an OS is being updated? For example, would the services that are being updated be unstable? 
An OS is generally more secure after being updated, but I would like it if someone could explain how an OS can be attacked (additional attack vectors, etc.) *while* it is being updated.

Answer (score 1):

According to FIRST, CVSS would be scored lower for a vulnerability that depends on certain conditions and it cannot be performed whenever the attacker wants to.

"A successful attack depends on conditions beyond the attacker's control. That is, a successful attack cannot be accomplished at will..."
from https://www.first.org/cvss/v3.0/specification-document

And from that perspective I would say a vulnerability witin the update functionality would have a lower risk.

But, practically if the OS doesn't have any vulnerability except one that is present when updating, I'd say it implies it is more vulnerable when updating.

On the top of my head I can think of these situations:

- MITM;
- insecure default configurations (after updating the settings could be more permissive);
- improper permissions placed on temporary files (during the update files could be created and used insecurely, eg. symlink vulnerabilities);
- race conditions, (eg. it creates a file that anyone can read from/write to and only after copying something it will change the permissions to be more restrictive).